# Анимация элементов (полет внутри родительского дива)

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, svg-animation, animate

Суть вопроса - хаотичное движение элементов внутри родительского дива с изменением направления при достижении края родителя.

Нашел вот такой скрипт:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  animateDiv($('.a'));
  animateDiv($('.b'));
  animateDiv($('.c'));

});

function makeNewPosition($container) {

  // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
  var h = $container.height() - 50;
  var w = $container.width() - 50;

  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

  return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv($target) {
  var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
  var oldq = $target.offset();
  var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

  $target.animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, speed, function() {
    animateDiv($target);
  });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

  var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
  var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

  var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

  var speedModifier = 0.1;

  var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

  return speed;

}
```

```css
div#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
}

div.a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}

div.b {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
}

div.c {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class='a'></div>
  <div class='b'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
</div>
```

Который почти идеально подходит.

Единственное, что не могу понять, каким образом заставить элементы менять направление только в случае, когда они достигают края родительского элемента?

Comment: Если ответы были полезны, отметьте их плюсами, более подходящий ответ Вам, хорошо бы отметить галочкой. Если есть вопросы, задавайте

Comment: https://cobwwweb.com/animated-dot-background-canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как я бы это сделал.

Вынес логику в одноименный метод и снабдил комментами

```js
let rnd = Math.random;
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.append(canvas);
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
document.body.style.margin = 0;
resize();

function logic(p) {
    // с небольшой вероятностью выбираем случайное направление
    if (rnd() > 0.995) 
        p.targetDir = rnd() * Math.PI * 2;
    // за пределами допустимого прямоугольника - поворачиваем в центр,
    // тут можно выбрать направление поумнее
    if (9 + Math.abs(p.x) > w / 2 || 9 + Math.abs(p.y) > h / 2) 
        p.targetDir = Math.atan2(p.y, p.x) - Math.PI;   
}

let pts = Array(10).fill(0) .map((e,i) => {
    let dir = rnd() * Math.PI * 2;
    let size = rnd() * 11 + 5;
    let speed = 1 + rnd() / size * 11; 
    let x = rnd() * w - w / 2;
    let y = rnd() * h - h / 2;
    let color = `hsl(${i*36},55%,66%)`;
    return {color, size, dir, targetDir: dir, speed, x, y};
});

function draw(t) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00000012";
    ctx.fillRect(-1e5, -1e5, 2e5, 2e5);
    pts.forEach((p, i) => {
        logic(p, t, i);
        p.x += Math.cos(p.dir) * p.speed;
        p.y += Math.sin(p.dir) * p.speed;
        p.dir = angleLerp(p.dir, p.targetDir, 0.1) + Math.sin(t/100+i)*0.03;
        ctx.translate(p.x, p.y);
        ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
        ctx.rotate(p.dir + Math.PI/2);
        ctx.fillRect(-p.size/4, -p.size/2, p.size/2, p.size);
        ctx.rotate(-p.dir - Math.PI/2);
        ctx.translate(-p.x, -p.y);
    });
}

function angleLerp(a0, a1, t) {
    var max = Math.PI*2;
    var da = (a1 - a0) % max;
    return a0 + (2*da % max - da)*t;
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener("resize", resize);

function resize() {
    w = canvas.width = innerWidth;
    h = canvas.height = innerHeight;
    ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Посмотрите, может будет интересен вариант решения SVG без JS.

К сожалению в SVG нет `rundom()`, поэтому это лишь иллюзия хаотичного движения элементов, но эффект достаточно интересно выглядит.

Если вам нужны другие объекты движения, то можно круги заменить на другие объекты

```
<circle cx="50%" cy="20%" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >

 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="2.8" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
```

Ниже полный код:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400">

<rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="25"  fill="green" stroke="#9D8500" stroke-width="15"/>
<circle cx="50%" cy="20%" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >

 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="2.8" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>

<circle cx="30%" cy="70%" r="3%" fill="url(#gradR)" >

 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="2.7" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="3.1" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>

 <radialGradient id="gradB" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>

 <radialGradient id="gradR" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="red" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(192,0,0)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(127,0,0)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(64,0,0)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>

</svg>
```

**Несколько прямоугольников.**
Легко можете поменять цвет прямоугольников и их количество.
Параметры анимации для достижения нужного эффекта можно менять здесь: `dur="2.8"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400">

<rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="15"  fill="orange" stroke="none" stroke-width="2"/>
<rect x="50%" y="20%" width="3%" height="3%" fill="red" >

 <animate attributeName="x" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="y" dur="2.8" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</rect>

<rect x="50%" y="20%" width="3%" height="3%" fill="green" >

 <animate attributeName="x" dur="2.7" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="y" dur="3.1" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</rect>  

<rect x="50%" y="20%" width="3%" height="3%" fill="dodgerblue" >

 <animate attributeName="x" dur="2.5" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="y" dur="3.3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</rect>

<rect x="50%" y="20%" width="3%" height="3%" fill="purple" >

 <animate attributeName="x" dur="2.6" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="y" dur="2" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</rect>

<rect x="50%" y="20%" width="3%" height="3%" fill="#1644C1" >

 <animate attributeName="x" dur="2.6" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="y" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</rect>


</svg>
```

Comment: Как всегда....)))))))))))

Answer (score 6):

Можно как-то так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  animateDiv($('.a'));
  animateDiv($('.b'));
  animateDiv($('.c'));
});

function makeNewPosition($container) {
  var h = $container.height() - 50;
  var w = $container.width() - 50;
  var side = Math.random()>0.5 ? 0: 1;
  var nh = 8 + (side ? h*side : Math.floor(Math.random() * h));
  var nw = 8 + (side ? Math.floor(Math.random() * w) : h*side);
  return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv($target) {
  var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
  var oldq = $target.offset();
  var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
  $target.animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, speed, function() {
    animateDiv($target);
  });
};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
  var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
  var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
  var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
  var speedModifier = 0.1;
  var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);
  return speed;
}
```

```css
div#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: orange;
}

div.a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

div.b {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

div.c {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class='a'></div>
  <div class='b'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
</div>
```

однако, наверное, лучше оперировать направлениями а не положениями

Comment: интересно смотрится, так неторопливо, вальяжно :) Код у тебя, обычно короче был (+) Иначе, если быстрее, рендеринг видно, шлейфы?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT тут я старался меньше менять код автора

Comment: В возможно так чтобы как он дошол до к краю родителя и изменил направление?